# Create inactive timestamp keyboard shortcut not working

Tags: emacs, org-mode

So, according to the Emacs manual, you can create inactive timestamps of the form `[1970-01-01 Thu]` by hitting `C-c !`.

However, doing so will result in my minibuffer displaying `C-c !-` waiting for further input. Hitting space or return doesn't work and just results in an error saying `C-c !-RET` isn't a valid command.

What exactly happened here? Is the command simply not defined by default? I'm fairly certain I don't have anything defined that globally overrides this, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Are you in an org-mode buffer? (check mode in status bar). You can check what is being called with `F1 k C-c !`.

Comment: @Juancho I'm indeed in the correct buffer, and doing as you suggest just results in the same.. It's expecting an input after !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you type `C-c ! <f1>` you'll see a list of all keybindings that start with `C-c !`. Does that help?

I don't think there's a timestamp function bound to `C-c !` by default, but there are plenty of results if you Google "Emacs timestamp".

Comment: it seems flycheck overwrote all the `C-c !` commands, is there a way for me to bind `C-c !!` to `org-time-stamp-inactive`? Or at least set `C-c !` to be active in org-mode only

Comment: Yes, `(define-key flycheck-mode-map (kbd "C-c ! !") 'org-time-stamp-inactive)`.

That way, if you're in `org-mode` but not `flycheck-mode`, `C-c !` will insert a timestamp. If you're in both `org-mode` and `flycheck-mode`, `C-c ! !` will insert a timestamp.

Comment: emacs says `flycheck-mode-map` is void, so I guess that's not the solution

Comment: Perhaps put `(require 'flycheck)` in you `.emacs`?